# Connection Reset by peer on android server application

Tags: android, sockets

I have an Activity called MainActivity and a Service called CameraService. CameraService acts as a server and listens to clients over socket. Whenever a client connects the Service triggers via MainActivity (and a BroadcastReceiver) the camera. When the camera returns onActivityResult it uses CameraService's out OutputStream (public static attribute) to send the photo back to the client.

`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {`

```
        try {
            byte[] bufferArray = new byte[(int)path.length()];

            Log.i(TAG, "Image size: " + Integer.toString(bufferArray.length));

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(bufferArray, 0, bufferArray.length);
            CameraService.out.write(bufferArray, 0, bufferArray.length);

            CameraService.out.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.i(TAG, stackTraceToString(e));
        }
```

The code above performs the photo send to the client via CameraService.out OutputStream. The problem is that the clients reset the connection (RST tcp flag) and server cannot send the whole image. Any ideas why might this happen??